# Apex regex pattern to match Space hyphen Integer

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have the following values for a custom picklist field

1. Lower - L1
2. Upper - L2
3. Side - L3

What is the regex pattern to match the above values?

Mainly this pattern

```
   {anylength of string}{one space}{one hyphen}{one space}{L charecter}{one digit integer}
```

I have tried something this way but not working

```
String message = 'Upper - L2';
String regex = '[a-zA-Z\\sL\\s\\d{1}]*';
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(message);
if(regexMatcher.matches() == true) {
   System.debug('Matched');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to make the regex using a character class, but that's simply incorrect.

You should find something like the following is more appropriate:

```
^.+ - L[0-9]$
```

This is:

- Matching the whole value (start at the beginning with "^" and end at the end with "$")
- Allowing any sequence of at least one character with ".+"
- explicitly matching space, hyphen, space (this doesn't match tabs etc.)
- explicitly matching "L" (this doesn't match "l")
- allowing a single numeric digit between 0 and 9

Comment: The ^ and $ are not strictly necessary for matches, as that method sets the match boundary to the entire string (but not harmful in this case, either).

Answer (score 3):

A single character class isn't going to help you here, as that will simply match anything, and you specified "*", meaning zero or more, so it'll even match an empty string!

You need the specific pattern to match, so:

```
String regex = '[a-zA-Z]+ - [a-zA-Z][0-9]';
```

Which covers all of your examples. The spaces and hyphen can be written normally, the first part specifies only letters (at least 1 because of "+"), and exactly one letter and number at the end.